# Use raw sql query in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, database

Good day. I have an sql query that I have already tested and worked with using mysql workbench. However, I want to integrate it into my Laravel application, such that I can also use the get() and paginate() functions on the result.
The query is shown below

```
SELECT applicable_areas.area
     , applicable_areas.id as id
     , count(stype) as supreme_court_cases
     , count(atype) as appeal_court_cases
  FROM applicable_areas
  JOIN (
           SELECT    1 AS atype, null AS stype, applicable_area_id, suitno FROM appeal_applicable_areas
            UNION
           SELECT null         ,    1         , applicable_area_id, suitno FROM supreme_applicable_areas
       ) AS area_types
    ON area_types.applicable_area_id = applicable_areas.id
  JOIN cp_cases_counsel
    ON cp_cases_counsel.suitno = area_types.suitno
 WHERE cp_cases_counsel.counsel_id = 38
 GROUP BY applicable_areas.id
 ORDER BY applicable_areas.area ASC;
```

On Laravel

```
$practice_areas = DB::connection('mysql2')->table('applicable_areas')
        ->select(DB::raw("applicable_areas.area
        , applicable_areas.id as id
        , COUNT(stype) as supreme_court_cases
        , COUNT(atype) as appeal_court_cases
     FROM applicable_areas
     JOIN (
              SELECT    1 AS atype, null AS stype, applicable_area_id, suitno FROM appeal_applicable_areas
               UNION
              SELECT null         ,    1         , applicable_area_id, suitno FROM supreme_applicable_areas
          ) AS area_types
       ON area_types.applicable_area_id = applicable_areas.id
     JOIN cp_cases_counsel
       ON cp_cases_counsel.suitno = area_types.suitno
    WHERE cp_cases_counsel.counsel_id = 38
    GROUP BY applicable_areas.id
    ORDER BY applicable_areas.area ASC"))->get();
```

Tried this as well:

````
$practice_areas = DB::connection('mysql2')->table('applicable_area')
        ->join(DB::raw("SELECT 1 AS atype, null AS stype, applicable_area_id, suitno FROM appeal_applicable_areas
        UNION
       SELECT null , 1 , applicable_area_id, suitno FROM supreme_applicable_areas
   ) AS area_types"),
        function($join){
            $join->on('area_types.applicable_area_id', '=', 'applicable_areas.id');
        })
        ->join('cp_cases_counsel', 'cp_cases_counsel.suitno','=','area_types.suitno')
        ->select('applicable_areas.id as id','applicable_areas.area','count(stype) as supreme_court_cases',
        'count(atype) as appeal_court_cases')
        ->where('cp_cases_counsel.counsel_id',38)
       ->groupBy('applicable_areas.id')->get();```
I get an error with that statement. Please, is there a way to do this?
Thanks.
````

Comment: what an error you get?

Answer (score -1):

$practice_areas = DB::select("SELECT applicable_areas.area
, applicable_areas.id as id
, COUNT(stype) as supreme_court_cases
, COUNT(atype) as appeal_court_cases
FROM applicable_areas
JOIN (
SELECT    1 AS atype, null AS stype, applicable_area_id, suitno FROM appeal_applicable_areas
UNION
SELECT null         ,    1         , applicable_area_id, suitno FROM supreme_applicable_areas
) AS area_types
ON area_types.applicable_area_id = applicable_areas.id
JOIN cp_cases_counsel
ON cp_cases_counsel.suitno = area_types.suitno
WHERE cp_cases_counsel.counsel_id = 38
GROUP BY applicable_areas.id
ORDER BY applicable_areas.area ASC")->get();